# how to Increase selected cell height of uitableview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell, selectedindex

this is what i want to achieve. When user tap on a cell, it expands showing some extra buttons on it.
Any tutorial or sample code in swift?
As i am a newbie, a beginner level and detailed approach will be appreciated.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jsrxv6nw03p5gk/profiles.png?dl=0
in this snapshot blue cell is selected one and white cell are normal cells.

Comment: have you try to search on google? there is lots of result for this

Comment: yes, i tried, but nothing helping me. mostly tutorial are teaching self resizing thing using autolayouts.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this;

Add property

```
var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
```

Add your custom Heights

```
let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 88.0
let unselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
```

After add custom height tableview codes

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            return selectedCellHeight
        }
        return unselectedCellHeight
    }
```

Comment: this exactly what i am doing, but the resized cell overlaps the neighboring cells, not completely but from the top and bottom part.